# How to send and receive values in android?

Tags: android

How to send and receive the values to the webservices in Android? .I am very new to android.Give some ideas to me...

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend going through some tutorial apps seen here- http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your response Mike

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample, was useful for me
[Calling Web Services in Android using HttpClient](http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you mean strings by values.

I would recommend using [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/examples.html) for the purpose as it is every easy to use. You could use ListNameValuePairs for sending values.

You could check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/send-post-data-in-android/2938787#2938787) to this question for a sample program as well.