# Android send a image and save url

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send post data in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/send-post-data-in-android)

How to send a image via http post along with the form data i.e image name etc

to a specified url .. which is the url of a **aspx**.

Comment: And why do you think they should be any different?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check this code for Sending Image with Title,Caption,Name etc,

```
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("You Link");
    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    reqEntity.addPart("name", new StringBody("Name"));
    reqEntity.addPart("Id", new StringBody("ID"));
    reqEntity.addPart("title",new StringBody("TITLE"));
    reqEntity.addPart("caption", new StringBody("Caption"));
    try{
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
        byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
        ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "forest.jpg");
        reqEntity.addPart("picture", bab);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        //Log.v("Exception in Image", ""+e);
        reqEntity.addPart("picture", new StringBody(""));
    }
    postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);       
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
    String sResponse;
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        s = s.append(sResponse);
    }
```

Where bitmap is the Image Bitmap.

Comment: Great one. What about video uploading?

Comment: But this is not happening on Android Studio @Venky

Comment: addpart is not working ??