# Android- POST multipart form data

Tags: android, http, post, http-post

I would like to send multipart form with video and data such as Email and name.
The following is my code and it does not work ,there is no response from the server

```
File file =new File(VideoPath);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", "LDGHT"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", "hhh@example.com"));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            httppost.setEntity(new FileEntity(file, "video/mp4"));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
```

Answer (score 24):

Check my Post for Sending Mutipart Data [Post Data to Server with Multipart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632737/android-send-a-file-to-url/7632849#7632849)..

Also Check this for Reference [Link](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/)

```
new Task_finder().execute();
```

Upload Video File to Server :

```
    public class Task_finder extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Facebook_Post_View.this);
    // can use UI thread here
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
        this.dialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        DataInputStream inStream = null;
        String existingFileName = file_path;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary =  "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
        String urlString = "YOUR PHP LINK FOR UPLOADING IMAGE";
        try{
            //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(existingFileName) );
            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Allow Outputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            // Don't use a cached copy.
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            // Use a post method.
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
            dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + upload_file_name + "\"" + lineEnd); // uploaded_file_name is the Name of the File to be uploaded
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0){
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException ex){
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe){
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }
        //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
        try {
            inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
            String str;
            while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null){
                Log.e("Debug","Server Response "+str);
                reponse_data=str;
            }
            inStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ioex){
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
        }
       return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks how to use this method "toByteArray()" for the video file

Comment: Thanks, but it dose not work ,Do you think there is problem in version 2.3.3 to connect to the server ?

Comment: @Dev That code is working copy of mine.. Surely it works.. Better post you full code here..

Comment: @Venky i tried your code i works perfectly , my question is that if i want to send other form data with video file ?

Comment: @chhameed I would like to know that as well

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately I was not successful to use Venky's code. After two day finally I found my solution and hope it helps those that have same problem. Feel free to modify the code since this code is based on my structure. 
Note: `bitmapProfileImage` is global variable that holds bitmap image (`Bitmap bitmapProfileImage;`)

```
public class ContentDownloader {

        public static String getHttpPutContent(String url, String token, MultipartEntity multipartEntity) {

            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPut put = new HttpPut(url);
                put.setHeader("token", token);
    //            Log.i(TAG, "Token=> " + token);
                Log.i(TAG, "Try to open=> " + url);

                MultipartEntity reqEntity = multipartEntity;
                put.setEntity(reqEntity);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(put);
                int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                Log.i(TAG, "Connection code: " + statusCode);

                HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                String serverResponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                Log.i(TAG, "Server response=> " + serverResponse);

                if(!isStatusOk(statusCode))
                    return null;

                return serverResponse;

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        } 

        /**
         *
         * @param statusCode
         * @return True if connection code is 2xx, False otherwise.
         */
        private static boolean isStatusOk(int statusCode) {
            if((statusCode >= HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)  &&  (statusCode <= HttpURLConnection.HTTP_PARTIAL))
                return true;

            return false;
        }
}
```

So in your activity/fragment you should have `AsyncTask` class. Add following code inside `doInBackground` method:

```
        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String content = "";
            String url = LinkManager.getUserProfileUrl();

            Person person = SpStorage.getPersonInfo(context);

                String imgPath = SpStorage.getProfilePicPath(context);
                String imgName = imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

                if(bitmapProfileImage == null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "bitmap is null. Try to get it from profile pic directory...");
                    String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                            File.separator + ImageDownloader.DIRECTORY_NAME + File.separator + PROFILE_PICS;
                    imgPath = new File(file_path, imgName).getAbsolutePath();
                    bitmapProfileImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath);
                }

                if(bitmapProfileImage != null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Image address: " + imgPath);

                    try {
                        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                        reqEntity.addPart("first_name", new StringBody(person.getName()));
                        reqEntity.addPart("last_name", new StringBody(""));
                        reqEntity.addPart("email",new StringBody(person.getEmail()));
                        reqEntity.addPart("birthday", new StringBody(person.getBirthDay()));
                        reqEntity.addPart("gender", new StringBody(person.getGender(person.getGender())));
                        reqEntity.addPart("orientation", new StringBody(person.getOrientation(person.getGender(), person.getLookingFor())));
                        reqEntity.addPart("relationship_status", new StringBody(person.getStatus(person.getStatus())));
                        reqEntity.addPart("city", new StringBody(person.getCity()));
                        reqEntity.addPart("about", new StringBody(person.getAboutMe()));
                        reqEntity.addPart("device_type", new StringBody("Android"));

                        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bitmapProfileImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, bos);
                        byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
                        ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "profilePic.png");
                        reqEntity.addPart("photo", bab);

                        content = ContentDownloader.getHttpPutContent(url, SpStorage.getToken(context), reqEntity);
                    }
                    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else
                    Log.e(TAG, "Image not found :(");


            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(content)) {
                return 0; // registration successful
            }

            return -1;
        }
```

Finally, in order to use `MultipartEntity`, You are needed to download 4 jar files. One is  [apache-mime4j](http://james.apache.org/mime4j/) and the rest are [httpclient, httpcore and httpmime](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi). You should extract jar files and copy/paste it int `./libs` folder of your project.

[Another use full sample](http://blog.tacticalnuclearstrike.com/2010/01/using-multipartentity-in-android-applications/)

Answer (score 3):

There is my working solution (I hope simpler) for sending image with post, using apache http libraries (very important here is boundary add It won't work without it in my connection). I hope it could help in such situation:

```
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
            byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(StaticData.AMBAJE_SERVER_URL + StaticData.AMBAJE_ADD_AMBAJ_TO_GROUP);

            String boundary = "-------------" + System.currentTimeMillis();

            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary);

            ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(imageBytes, "pic.png");
            StringBody sbOwner = new StringBody(StaticData.loggedUserId, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
            StringBody sbGroup = new StringBody("group", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);

            HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                    .setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
                    .setBoundary(boundary)
                    .addPart("group", sbGroup)
                    .addPart("owner", sbOwner)
                    .addPart("image", bab)
                    .build();

            httpPost.setEntity(entity);

            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
                ...then reading response
```

Comment: the boundary tidbit helped me solve a very similar issue. you saved me a great deal of grief.