# How can we upload a video file using REST API in Rails

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json, video

I want to upload a video file from IOS/Android client to RAILS JSON api server.

I am trying this from a rails api only application. For image uploading i used to encode image in base64 format and pass this Base64 value as a JSON param. But if i use the same logic, it is not practical for a large file, say for 10MB or 20MB.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually a valid option to upload the file encoded in Base64 for a normal JSON-API request. You can decode the String in the Rails controller roughly with the following code:

```
def upload_action_method
  file = StringIO.new(Base64.decode(params[:file_data])
end
```

The disadvantage of this approach is how you already recognized the increased filesize of roughly ~33%.
The other way would be to perform a `multi-part/form-data` POST request from the IOS or Android device. This way, Rails should get access for the File object in the params hash, just like a normal file upload form. You need to build a valid request for the native device manually or use a existing library. I referenced you 2 other answers showing code examples for building a multipart request:
**Android**: [Android- POST multipart form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645284/android-post-multipart-form-data)
**IOS**: [Upload image with parameters in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162616/upload-image-with-parameters-in-swift)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried to implement the above said method. I used postman to pass the params with 'form-data' request, but i am getting a json parse error.

' JSON::ParserError at /tasks
==============================

> 822: unexpected token at ------WebKitFormBoundarya2JDVVYPSXaBioSk
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="price"

200
------WebKitFormBoundarya2JDVVYPSXaBioSk
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pic"; filename="SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4"
Content-Type: video/mp4 '

What i did, I selected a video file through postman and send the request. Can you help?