# How to store data on internet then download it to my app?

Tags: android, mysql

I want to store text, images, usernames , passwords into servers on internet then get it when I want (example: Facebook News Feed) but i don't know how. Is there programming languages that should I learn ? I learnt android building apps and java .

I heard about GoDaddy servers hosting but I don't know if it will help me in 
my situation or not!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to store the data in server first of all you need an API to connect the to the server. An api is an intermediary which will carry your data to the server and returns back with a response whether data was saved or not.
In a same way, When you want to get the data back from server, you need another api to take your request to server and returns back with the data.
So an api is the key thing to connect the android device with server. You can learn more about api here https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.mulesoft.com/resources/api/what-is-an-api&ved=2ahUKEwiBgY3A8vzjAhXZfX0KHfJABW0QFjAhegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw2YmD996I4_rG4y0iSbKmEe
Remember, just like your android project, server is also an application, a project where someone writes his codes that process your request of saving/getting the data. 
Even though you don't have to learn another language to write code for server and api, you can use Java to build the web application, you need to learn about some frameworks like spring boot, which provides you with the features which ease your work and SQL for connect with the storage(DataBase) available in server.
Yes GoDaddy will definitely help you hosting your server. 
In android side, you need a networking library e.g Retrofit (or you can write your own) to access those apis.

Like @Tarun Sharma mentioned, this question/topic is widely broad, you have lots of other options and alternatives available out there to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

1. first you need to make specific JSON data like youtube and facbook api have.
2. second u can add images,video using multipart [multipart data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645284/android-post-multipart-form-data) to server. 
   java and android sufficient to send data from android end. there will be different story for server. The question is widely broad