# Is it possible to store zip file in Google app engine blob store and download it In android application

Tags: android, google-app-engine, zip, blobstore

Hi I am new to use **Google App Engine**.My requirement is store **Large Zip file** in a Blob Store and retrieve to my android application when user click a download option It is possible?Can some one Give Tutorial link to how can effectively use android app engine blob store in android application.
Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: yes you can.

First of all you will have to complete the example on how to [upload stuff using Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview) and then experimenting with the [Google Cloud Storage](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#using-blobstore-with-gcs) because it will be much cheaper in the long run.

After completing that you will realise that in order to upload, all you'll have to do is to [POST multipart data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7632849/8418) either from Android or using any other method you would like. In that tutorial is also very obvious on how you could download any file back to your Android application.

You could also experiment with one of my examples for [uploading files](http://upload.gae-init.appspot.com/resource/upload/) either on Blobstore or on Cloud Storage. In that particular example you are allowed to upload only images and PDF documents, but it's very easy to modify and accepting only ZIP files or whatever else you might want.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Google Cloud Storage would be more appropriate.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/