# Using Authorize for Uploading from Android to ASP.NET

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, upload

I'm uploading an image from my **android device** to my **ASP.NET MVC web application** and I can't seem to get the `[Authorize]` function working properly.

I access my **ASP.NET MVC web application** in a **WebView** on my **android device** and the `[Authorize]` works fine. When I upload an image using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632737/android-send-a-image-and-save-url/) the user log-in is forgotten and the upload won't have enough permission to work. When I remove the `[Authorize]` from the upload controller the upload works fine from the android.

Is there any reason why the method linked above would have it so the account information is forgotten? Perhaps because it is done on the different thread on the android?

Is it possible to have the `[Authorize]` method work when uploading from an android to the ASP.NET MVC web service?