# Send picture taken from android to .net web application (to store it in database)

Tags: android, asp.net, json, svc

I'm trying to upload some photos taken by an application in a distant database. To be clear :

- I take a piture from my app
- I send if to a web service (witten in .net, svc file)
- The WS upload it in the database

The way i'm doing it : i'm sending the byte[] recovered from the picture that way

```
String url = MyAddress + "insert_img?login='"
                    + login_result + "'&epc='" + code + "'&title='" + t
                    + "'&image='" + base64EncodedString + "'&descrip='" + d
                    + "'";
            BufferedReader inStream = null;
            System.out.println(url);
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpR = new HttpGet(url);
            httpR.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpR.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpR);
```

My problem is that I have to compress A LOT the picture in order it to be send. The picture, or base64EncodedString field, is created like that :

```
Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

mImageView.setImageDrawable(null);
mImageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 1, baos);

byte[] outputByteArray = baos.toByteArray();

base64EncodedString = Base64.encodeToString(outputByteArray, Base64.NO_WRAP + Base64.URL_SAFE);
```

As you can see, the image is very very very compressed, and when I recover it it's more or less a 4-colors stamp. And if I do not compress it a lot, image is not inserted.
So first of all : Am I doing it the right way to deal ? And also, why is there no insertion when the picture is too big and how, if possible, to track the error ?

Thanks !

---

EDIT :

I've modified my code that way, server side :

```
public string insert_report(Stream stream)
    {
        string login = "";
        string epc = "";
        string title = "";
        string image = "";
        string descrip = "";
        MultipartParser parser = new MultipartParser(stream);
        Entities entities = new Entities();
        string res = ""; 
        if (parser != null && parser.Success)
        {
            res += parser.Filename;
            foreach (var content in parser.MyContents)
            {
                string name = content.PropertyName;
                string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(content.Data);
                res += "name : " + name +"---";
                res += "content : " + str+"---";

                if (name.Contains("login"))
                {
                    login = str;
                }
                if (name.Contains("epc"))
                {
                    epc = str;
                }
                if (name.Contains("title"))
                {
                    title = str;
                }
                if (name.Contains("image"))
                {
                    image = str;
                }
                if (name.Contains("descrip"))
                {
                    descrip = str;
                }
            }
        }
        res+= " res returned by server : "+ entities.insert_report(login, epc, title, image, descrip);
        entities.SaveChanges();
        return res;
    }
```

But there are some problems : the insert_report function return -1... How do I recover the error given by that function ?

Answer (score 2):

Do you receive 414 (Request-URI Too Long) error? You should use HTTP POST method to upload your images as POST body - no Base64 encoding will be also required. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/7632849/2714032

Comment: I've edited my question in order you to see the two sides of the application. I'm gonna work with you suggestion, does it change anything for the called function WS side ? Thanks !

Comment: Yes, WS part also needs to be modified in order to handle multipart/form-data - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7460231/2714032

Comment: I've updated my question according to your considerations, have a look :) (since it's not working...)