# Send byte[] from android volley to asp.net mvc

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, android-volley

I am trying to upload an image from android to asp.net mvc webapp. I've the following code to upload image on android part -

```
   public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}

private String UPLOAD_URL ="UploadSignature?id=1";

private String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
private String KEY_NAME = "name";
private Bitmap bitmap;

private void uploadImage(){

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

            String image = getStringImage(bitmap);               
            String name = "firstImage";               
            Map<String,String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            params.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
            params.put(KEY_NAME, name);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

In asp.net mvc controller-

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadSignatureTwo(byte[] Data)
{
   System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes( @"D:\test.jpg", Data);
}
```

But it says `Data can not be null`.

Any help?

Comment: Does `Data` have any value? check that  in your controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android send a image and save url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632737/android-send-a-image-and-save-url)

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240177/working-post-multipart-request-with-volley-and-without-httpentity