# Saving an image for image recognition via REST on raspberryPi

Tags: android, python, flask, raspberry-pi2, image-recognition

I am doing a project for image recognition. I want to send an image or a video from an android app to the raspberryPi, that is my server (I use flask), and make the recognition on the server and then send back the result to android. I want to do this with REST and python. So how can I do this? 
I am new to all of this so any help is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as your raspberryPi server use flask, so you can done the task through HTTP and your android phone browser as client.
raspberryPi as server should have the following api:
Chose a image and upload, then recognition and send the result back.

That all.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using flask, you need to implement REST endpoint that handles multipart/form-data, the example of such endpoint you can find [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/fileuploads/).

On the client part (in your case - android app) you need to implement sending of the image to that endpoint, example you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632737/android-send-a-file-to-url/7632849#7632849).

Comment: Thank you for your response!
I make the recognition and get, perhaps, the name of the person, how i will handle it in android and show it to the user? I didn't understand!

Comment: After you execute request, you will receive HttpResponse and you can extract responce content like that :
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
String json = reader.readLine();