# HTTPPOST to tweet from an application

Tags: android, twitter, http-post

is it possible to tweet by sending an HTTP post request from our app. If so, can anyone tell how is that done.

Comment: The Twitter API: https://dev.twitter.com/docs

Comment: A simple Google search would have turned up http://twitter4j.org/

Answer (score 0):

As @Marc B suggests, if you check out the [Twitter API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update), you will find that publishing a tweet via POST is achievable by sending a request to "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json" with the parameters outlined in the API docs.

Do you have a unique question regarding your application?  You may wish to edit your question to provide a detailed description of your specific situation so that we can be more helpful.

Comment: i dont know how to exactly use https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json.. i went through the docs, but didint understand how to implement it

Comment: If you need to know how to POST data, check out [this answer by PrimalPop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/send-post-data-in-android).  Is that what you were looking for?