# Trying to POST sender's mobile number and message recieved via SMS to a website.no errors but still the app dsnt open.Can you please suggest a way?

Tags: android

I am trying to POST sender's mobile number and message received via SMS to a    website..there are no errors but still the app doesn't open. Can you please suggest a way??

This is the manifest.xml file:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<receiver android:name=".receiver.SMSReceiver" android:enabled="true">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SmsReceiveActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

This is the SMSReceive.java:

```
package com.wissen.sms.receiver;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneNumberUtils;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMSReceive extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) {
smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
}
String mobile = PhoneNumberUtils.getNumberFromIntent(intent, context);
// show first message
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
"Received SMS: " + smsMessage[0].getMessageBody(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
    try {
    // Construct data
    String xyz = smsMessage[0].getMessageBody();    
    String data = URLEncoder.encode("test", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(xyz,       "UTF-8");
    data = data + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("mobile", "UTF-8") + "=" +    URLEncoder.encode(mobile, "UTF-8");

    //   http://www.medibeep.in/xyz.php?test=123&mobile=1234556
    // Send data
    URL url = new URL("http://www.medibeep.in/xyz.php");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(data);
    wr.flush();

    // Get the response
    BufferedReader rd = new             BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line1;
    while ((line1 = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line1);
    }
    wr.close();
    rd.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
}
```

Context:

```
[2012-02-02 22:28:19 - smsReceive] Android Launch!
[2012-02-02 22:28:19 - smsReceive] adb is running normally.
[2012-02-02 22:28:19 - smsReceive] Performing com.wissen.sms.receiver.SmsReceiveActivity activity launch
[2012-02-02 22:28:19 - smsReceive] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2012-02-02 22:28:24 - smsReceive] Uploading smsReceive.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-02-02 22:28:24 - smsReceive] Installing smsReceive.apk...
[2012-02-02 22:28:31 - smsReceive] Failed to install smsReceive.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2012-02-02 22:28:31 - smsReceive] (null)
[2012-02-02 22:28:32 - smsReceive] Launch canceled!
[2012-02-02 22:30:27 - smsReceive] Failed to install smsReceive.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2012-02-02 22:30:27 - smsReceive] (null)
[2012-02-02 22:30:27 - smsReceive] Launch canceled!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're not actually `POST`ing your data from what I can see. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android) and you should be able to figure out how to `POST`.

Secondly, you need to start a `Service` from your `BroadcastReceiver` and then do the `POST` in the `Service`. When you call it in the `BroadcastReceiver`, it likely won't have time to complete the request.

Thirdly, as Hydrangea mentioned, you need to declare your receiver in the `Manifest`

Comment: can you tell how to start service from broadcastreceiver ?

Comment: You would create an explicit intent for the `Service` and call `startService(intent)`. If you don't know how to do all this, I would suggest reading more of http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html

Answer (score 0):

To start with: in your manifest, the receiver should be inside the application tags.

Comment: i put receiver in application tags.Still the app crashes.