# Fill Form Data in Android

Tags: android, autofill

I am new to Android development. Using android, I am trying to go to a certain website which is not under my control(developed by someone else  and I can't change), fill the data in form fields.

Using WebView control, i am able to load the given URL. But i am stuck with sending/filling data to form fields.

How do i proceed with that?

Comment: yes i want to auto fill the form through my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probobly need to do somthing like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android).

You should realy check with the person responsible for the website.  If you can get a bit of co-operation then they are less likely to change the form on you and break your code.  I have a similar senario and the other party is very happy and will at least inform me before any major changes occure.