# How to call php file to send mail ?? , Android

Tags: android, email, post

I have the following mail.php file :

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
$from = $_POST['from'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = "From: ".$name."\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['message'];
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

I have following layout to send mail from my app:
[image]

I want to send mail to static mail eg: mymail@mail.com after clicking send button.
How can i send mail by calling above php file.
I heard about post method to call above php file
But dont have any idea about it.
Help Please !

Comment: you'll have to send a request to your server through HTTP/s. Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android

Comment: [Google is your friend](https://www.google.pt/search?q=java+http+post). http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/post.html In this example `key1`, `key2`, `keyn` would map to your PHP `$_POST` fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here it is:

```
    public static void sendData(String name, String to, String from, String subject, String message)
    {
        String content = "";

        try
        {               
            /* Sends data through a HTTP POST request */
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://your.website.com");
            List <NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("to", to));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("from", from));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subject", subject));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", message));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));

            /* Reads the server response */
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            int chr;
            while ((chr = in.read()) != -1)
            {
                sb.append((char) chr);
            }
            content = sb.toString();
            in.close();

            /* If there is a response, display it */
            if (!content.equals(""))
            {
                Log.i("HTTP Response", content);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: str = str.replaceAll("(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)", "<br />");

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to load web view or write a web service and pass the parameters as JSON.

Comment: do not forget to add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission> to the manifest either