# How do I Post Data in Android?

Tags: android, http, postdata

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android) topic for PostData using http. but it doesn't work.

What's wrong?

I also requested `Android.permission.INTERNET` in the `manifest`.

```
    public void postData() {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http:/mysite.com/postTest.php");
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pw", "12456"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        tv.setText(response.toString());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        //
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //
    }
}
```

**Edit**

My application will be terminated with this message :
`Unfortunately PostDataProject has stopped.`

Comment: "it doesn't work" - no exception, no description, no idea what the problem is.

Comment: My question is edited. Thanks

Comment: Post a full stack-trace when having one.

Comment: Problem solved. Was a silly mistake. Sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = responce.getEntity();
// convert stream to String 
BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
sb1.append(line);
}
tv.setText(sb1.toString());
```

and u can direclty set to textview if data is only for textvew or small:

```
tv.setText(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
```

and use this:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mysite.com/postTest.php");
```

instead of

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http:/mysite.com/postTest.php");
```

Comment: I traced the code. the error is happing in this line : `HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);`

Comment: you are missing // after http:/

Answer (score 1):

try to get response with `EntityUtils` http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html

```
 tv.setText(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
```