# Proper HTTP POST request in Android

Tags: android, http, request

Hi How do I properly make HTTP post request in android with this json based  API.

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST \
-d '{    
  "service_key": "e93facc04764012d7bfb002500d5d1a6",
  "incident_key": "srv01/HTTP",
  "event_type": "trigger",
  "description": "FAILURE for production/HTTP on machine srv01.acme.com"
  }
}' \
"https://events.pagerduty.com/generic/2010-04-15/create_event.json"
```

I have this code but it is giving me status error of 400 - https://gist.github.com/26af7af09b509c0e8c2a#comments

Comment: See the answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android

Comment: this is the full documentation of that API - http://developer.pagerduty.com/documentation/integration/events/trigger

I don't know if I am actually making a request..

Comment: Hi I think that is the same code I am using.. https://gist.github.com/3fb2d2249152eb3359d4

I am not sure if I am passing the parameters correctly

Comment: Where you do this API call? do you use an AsyncTask?

Comment: post your logcat messages.

Comment: @phemt,

I would like to do this API call to resolve an incident from pagerduty..

Comment: @Naeem 
this is my logcat message - https://gist.github.com/a6a965893884c8371013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some code somewhere else here and it worked... :)

```
public void requestAction(String service_key, String event_type, String incident_key, String description) 
{
    HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String message;
    HttpPost p = new HttpPost("https://events.pagerduty.com/generic/2010-04-15/create_event.json");
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    try 
    {
        object.put("service_key", service_key); 
        object.put("event_type", event_type);
        object.put("incident_key", incident_key);
        object.put("description","PI RedPhone: "+description);
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { }
    try 
    {
        message = object.toString();
        p.setEntity(new StringEntity(message, "UTF8"));
        p.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        HttpResponse resp = hc.execute(p);
        Log.d("Status line", "" + resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    } catch (Exception e) 
        {e.printStackTrace();}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you requested permission to access the network? See this question (possible duplicate):

[Make an HTTP request with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

needs to be in your manifest.

Comment: yes I have this in my manifest -
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Why don't you log the exceptions in your code? The answer may be there, not logging exceptions is bad practice.

Comment: Do you have suggestion why I am receiving status 400?
this is my lates code and I think it has something to do with the sequestion of jason object? - https://gist.github.com/26af7af09b509c0e8c2a#comments

Comment: I am receiving this errors

response: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Json: {"description":"test","service_key":"c2181xxxxx3d0xxe57","event_type":"trigger"}
Status code: 400