# BasicHttpParams doesn't work as expected

Tags: android, http, parameters

I'm very new to android and I have few problem working with `BasicHttpParams`.

I wish to hit this url in this format `http://10.0.2.2:8080/test/j_spring_security_check?j_password=something&j_username=anbto&ajax=true&`

This should be a `POST` call. The `baseUrl` is `http://10.0.2.2:8080/test/j_spring_security_check` and for params I have a `Map<String,String>` which value is `[j_password:something, j_username:something, ajax:true]`

I have a code like this:

```
    for(String param : params.keySet()) {
        httpParams.setParameter(param, params.get(param));
    }
```

where `httpParams` is a `BasicHttpParams` and when I call `post.setParams(httpParams);` I get the whole response of my page.

I actually I should get only JSON as a response (since I set `ajax` param to `true`) :

```
 {"error":"Sorry, we were not able to find a user with that username and password."}
```

But it doesn't.

But when I change the `baseUrl` to `http://10.0.2.2:8080/test/j_spring_security_check?j_password=something&j_username=anbto&ajax=true&` and skip setting up the params , I get the JSON response.

Not sure where I'm making the mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android) a good answer how send HttpPost in android