# Allow users to create an activity/forum

Tags: android, eclipse

I am starting to develop an android app that allows users to post ads. When a user has logged in they can post ads for things they are selling. There are different sections i.e. cars, books, DVDs etc.

I need help with the task of allowing a user to submit their add so others can browse it! A lot like this help forum (allowing people to post things)!

I have looked through a few android app books and online and cant find anything!

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Posting to an existing website?  If they have an API, study it.  If they don't, you can't.  To a new website?  Don't start with an android app, you need to start with a website, webservices, database design, etc.  And if you need to ask for all that, you aren't qualified to write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking to do a CraigsList kind of a thing, but in a mobile application.

You will need a server side application that will receive and distribute the ads along with the mobile client that will display the adds and give people the ability to post.

For the server side application, you can look into [Google App Engine](https://appengine.google.com/).  Since you're developing for android in eclipse, I gather that you are working with Java.  Google App Engine apps can be written in Java and hosted for free to get started.  If you want to go a more general route, look into building a [Servlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet), hosting it in something like [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/).

Once you have the server side application in place, it's just a matter of sending your data to it from within your mobile application.  [Here's an answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android) that shows how to do it.

Comment: Thanks that should do it!!