# How to execute RESTful POST requests from Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to execute a REST Post for the first time and I don't quite know where to begin.

I'm interacting with the [WordPress REST API](http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/), and am trying to utilize [this](http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1/post/sites/%24site/posts/%24post_ID/replies/new/) endpoint: `/sites/$site/posts/$post_ID/replies/new`, which is used to submit a new comment to a certain post.

I think I have a good grasp on working with GET requests, as I've successfully handled several of them. With those, I could say everything I needed to say to the server vis a vis the URL, but it seems there must be another step with POST requests. And my question is: What is that step(s)?

Do I wrap the content I want to submit into a JSONObject and post that? If so, how do I post it? Do I need to construct a statement somehow, similar to how I would construct a statement to execute on a database? Or is it indeed possible to pass my content along via the URL, as request parameters?

I'm aware that this question is a little on the open-ended side for SO, but I've been unable to find a good tutorial that answers these questions. If you know of one, please suggest it.

(I'm doing this all in an Android app)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My answer is taken straight from another answer on SO seen here [Sending POST data in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android) but ive cut and past the answer here for conveneience, Hope this helps

Http Client from Apache Commons is the way to go. It is already included in android. Here's a simple example of how to do HTTP Post using it.

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "Hi"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a script on your server, your POST interacts with that script and inturn that script works with your database.

A typical scenario will be:

Java HTTP POST ~~~> PHP ~~~~> MySql.

A good starting point to learn PHP will be to checkout PHPAcademy tutorials on youtube.

http://www.youtube.com/course?list=EC442FA2C127377F07

PHP will as well help you encode the result in JSON and post it back to your client.