# Android error "Unable to start activity" in main activity

Tags: java, php, android

I'm following the first answer [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android), and it doesn't work! I don't know why; please, if someone can help me, it would be appreciated.

This is my code:

```
package com.example.enviarphp;

//All the import is here

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://appandroid.comuv.com/index.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        Log.i( "Anda el try", "anda el try");
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dato", "Probandooo"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        Log.i( "se esta por ejecutar", "se esta por ejecutar");
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        Log.i( "se ejecutar", "se ejecutar");
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        throw new AssertionError("IO Error");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        throw new AssertionError("Client Protocol Error");

    }
}

}
```

And this is my PHP file:

```
<?php

$conexion = mysql_connect("base","name","password") or die ("Error al conectar a la base de datos.");

 mysql_select_db("name2",$conexion);

 $dato = $_POST['dato'];

 $sql="INSERT INTO Mensajes(id,mensaje) VALUES(null,$dato)";

 mysql_query($sql);

 ?>
```

LogCat error:

```
06-17 16:09:24.779: I/Anda el try(9916): anda el try
06-17 16:09:24.829: I/se esta por ejecutar(9916): se esta por ejecutar
06-17 16:09:24.919: D/AndroidRuntime(9916): Shutting down VM
06-17 16:09:24.919: W/dalvikvm(9916): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a4b1f8)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.enviarphp/com.example.enviarphp.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2079)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     at com.example.enviarphp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-17 16:09:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(9916):     ... 11 more
```

Thanks a lot! I hope somebody can help me with my problem, I've tried everything I know.

Comment: what part doesn't work?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is a completely useless description of the problem.

Comment: And try echoing and printing some data to check the flow of code.

Comment: Other than the wide open SQL injection vulnerability, what indication do you have that "it doesn't work"?  Is there an error message?  An unexpected behavior?  We can't test this for you, you have to tell us what's going on at runtime.

Comment: I'm uploading my logcat, the code works up to the logcat Log.i( "se ejecutar", "se ejecutar"); and from there all are errors

Comment: Here is the logcat http://db.tt/PuLkYGLL

Comment: this answer will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299/794088

Comment: @forgivegod in wich way? I don't get the point :P

Comment: please try to use more descriptive question titles. Keep in mind this is the main resource used for searching for questions for future generations.

Comment: yeah, when I know where the problem is I could put a reasonable title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

You are performing network I/O on the main application thread. You need to move this to a background thread, perhaps one managed by an `AsyncTask`.