# Android Send Post Data To Server

Tags: android, post

This is a possible duplicate of [Sending POST data in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android)

I used this code to send post data to server using android

```
public void postData() {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.mysite.com/android.php");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "Hi"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }
```

But when I run this app it shows this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.senddata/com.example.senddata.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Whats problem? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the below code inside your mainactivityactivity below setContentView() to avoid networkOnmainThread exception..

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }
```

But, doing heavy operation inside background thread using AsyncTask without blocking main thread would be great!

And also refer this link...

[AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

Answer (score 1):

Call the postData using an asyntask, in the doInBackground of asyntask. Do not call it from the mainThread

Answer (score 0):

You can't do Networking related tasks on Main Thread use `AsyncTask` Class instead