# Send data from android to servlet and get data from the servlet

Tags: android, mysql, servlets

i am working on a app where i have to make a registration and login form in android. i want to connect remote database with android through servlet . i have succeded to make a login system with the help from net, but the android code used "AsyncTask" which is very difficult to me to understoop .

if you can support me giving some link or simple source code which can send some data from android to servlet and get data from the servlet.

Comment: This is a site to get help with specific problems, not a place to have your work done for you.  If you want something done for you, find a freelancing site and hire someone.

Comment: Not so hard with new entry @GabeSechan.. :D Anyway, you're right. It's not easy to answer a question like this without developing an entire class, but you can see this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android] to know-how POST data to a server. Use asynktask [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html] for  perform this network operation (it's a very simple class if you read the doc). For data retrieving, just made your servelt response to request with a JSON. From android you can easily parse it, and get all the data you want!