# Android: Sending JSON to a C# webservice

Tags: c#, java, android, json, web-services

I'm currently trying to send a JSON string from an android app to a C# webservice I made.  The webservice code is simply:

 `public void PostLocationsAndroid(string data)
 {
  //DO STUFF
 }`

However all my requests end up with `data` being null.  Here's how I'm trying to consume the webservice in the android app:

`public void postData(String myValue) {
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://myurl.com/myserver/PostLocationsAndroid");
try {
 StringEntity se = new StringEntity(myValue);
 se.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
 httppost.setEntity(se);
 httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
 HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
 params.setParameter("data", valueIWantToSend);
 httppost.setParams(params);

 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
}`

I've tried several different ways, this is my most recent failure.

Comment: Try to call api in advance REST api client. See if you are getting proper response or not. If not then most probably it's issue of web services.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the answer from this question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2938787/389141

It seems to be very similar to the issue you are running into right now.

Comment: Yep, I tried a very similar method to that, but I used a <code>StringEntity</code> since I just wanted to post a JSON string.  I still get <code>data</code> as being null.  I wonder if I'm passing in my parameter incorrectly?

Comment: I'm not sure on that. I haven't ever tried using StringEntity. I had better luck using the answer from that question. If that doesn't work sadly I'm not sure what the issue is :(

Comment: What did your webservice method look like?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are passing a JSON string?

Try the below code (I have used similar in my code and works).

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
 jsonObject.put("data", valueIWantToSend);

 HttpResponse httpResponse = handleJsonPost(url, jsonObject);

public HttpResponse handleJsonPost(String url, JSONObject jsonObject)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException, ClientProtocolException {
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

    if (jsonObject != null) {
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
        httpPost.setEntity(se);
    }

    return new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpPost);
}
```