# Android studio: Pass data from android to php

Tags: php, android

I have two string ,how can i pass two string from android code to php? I have the follow code to connect my php:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.101/webservice/index.php");

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Comment: Here are some related questions

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using GET, this way, for example?

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
String string1 = "A";
String string2 = "B";
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.101/webservice/index.php?string1=" + string1 + "&string2=" + string2);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

And, in PHP, for example:

```
<?php
    $string1 = $_GET["string1"]);
    $string2 = $_GET["string2"]);
?>
```

Comment: how about the boolean??

Comment: Which boolean? Didn't you ask for "two string(s)"?

Comment: If you need to pass boolean values using GET or POST, you have to convert them to string... For example to strings "true" and "false", or "T" and "F"...

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
try {
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("StringOne", stringOne));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("StringTwo", stringTwo));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

In PHP:

```
<?php

 $stringOne = $_POST["StringOne"];
 $stringTwo = $_POST["StringTwo"];
?>
```

Comment: how to get the value in php then?? could you please provide the code for getting the value in php as well? thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Use this code snippet.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dataOne", "Hello"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dataTwo", "Android World"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Comment: how to get the value in php then?? could you please provide the code for getting the value in php as well? thank you so much

Comment: import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient; cannot be resolved

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to implement an AsyncTask to configure this task.
You can find out more on how to implement AsyncTask on [Android Developers | Async Task](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask).

Then in method `doInBackground(String...strings)` :

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings)  // Connect to the database, write query and add items to array list
    {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                .url("http://example.gr/yourscript.php?id="+id+
                        "&anotherParam="+param)  //send parameteres to php script
                .build();
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            String responseString = response.body().string();
            System.out.println(responseString);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return x;
    }
```

You should also have a php script where you will fetch the parameters you need to pass via GET.
e.g. `$id = $_GET['id'];`