# I need an alternative option to HttpClient in Android to send data to PHP as it is no longer supported

Tags: java, android, api, http-post, apache-commons-httpclient

Currently I'm using `HttpClient`, `HttpPost` to send data to my `PHP server` from an `Android app` but all those methods were deprecated in API 22 and removed in API 23, so what are the alternative options to it?

I searched everywhere but I didn't find anything.

Comment: You should clarify what platform you are on (java, php, ruby?) and what library+version you are using now, and to what library+version you are trying to update to (include the exact versions and library names).

Comment: I am sending data from Android app to PHP using HttpPost and HttpClient but these methods are deprecated in the new update of API 22 so i need some option to that

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [HttpClient](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes#behavior-apache-http-client) was deprecated and now removed:

`org.apache.http.client.HttpClient`:

> This interface was deprecated in API level 22.
>   Please use openConnection() instead. Please visit this webpage for further details.

means that you should switch to `java.net.URL.openConnection()`.

See also the new [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) documentation.

Here's how you could do it:

```
URL url = new URL("http://some-server");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

// read the response
System.out.println("Response Code: " + conn.getResponseCode());
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
String response = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(response);
```

`IOUtils` documentation: [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)
`IOUtils` Maven dependency: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.commons|commons-io|1.3.2|jar

Comment: What is `IOUtils` in your answer?

Comment: Improved the answer by adding links to the `Commons IO` (`IOUtils`) documentation and the maven search site.

Answer (score 43):

I've also encountered with this problem to solve that I've made my own class.
Which based on java.net, and supports up to android's API 24 
please check it out:
[HttpRequest.java](http://pastebin.com/wXbqGMqR)

Using this class you can easily:

1. Send Http `GET` request
2. Send Http `POST` request
3. Send Http `PUT` request
4. Send Http `DELETE`
5. Send request without extra data params & check response `HTTP status code`
6. Add custom `HTTP Headers` to request (using varargs)
7. Add data params as `String` query to request
8. Add data params as `HashMap` {key=value}
9. Accept Response as `String`
10. Accept Response as `JSONObject`
11. Accept response as `byte []` Array of bytes (useful for files)

and any combination of those - just with one single line of code)

Here are a few examples:

```
//Consider next request: 
HttpRequest req=new HttpRequest("http://host:port/path");
```

**Example 1**:

```
//prepare Http Post request and send to "http://host:port/path" with data params name=Bubu and age=29, return true - if worked
req.prepare(HttpRequest.Method.POST).withData("name=Bubu&age=29").send();
```

**Example 2**:

```
// prepare http get request,  send to "http://host:port/path" and read server's response as String 
req.prepare().sendAndReadString();
```

**Example 3**:

```
// prepare Http Post request and send to "http://host:port/path" with data params name=Bubu and age=29 and read server's response as JSONObject 
HashMap<String, String>params=new HashMap<>();
params.put("name", "Groot"); 
params.put("age", "29");
req.prepare(HttpRequest.Method.POST).withData(params).sendAndReadJSON();
```

**Example 4**:

```
//send Http Post request to "http://url.com/b.c" in background  using AsyncTask
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){
        protected String doInBackground(Void[] params) {
            String response="";
            try {
                response=new HttpRequest("http://url.com/b.c").prepare(HttpRequest.Method.POST).sendAndReadString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                response=e.getMessage();
            }
            return response;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //do something with response
        }
    }.execute();
```

**Example 5**:

```
//Send Http PUT request to: "http://some.url" with request header:
String json="{\"name\":\"Deadpool\",\"age\":40}";//JSON that we need to send
String url="http://some.url";//URL address where we need to send it 
HttpRequest req=new HttpRequest(url);//HttpRequest to url: "http://some.url"
req.withHeaders("Content-Type: application/json");//add request header: "Content-Type: application/json"
req.prepare(HttpRequest.Method.PUT);//Set HttpRequest method as PUT
req.withData(json);//Add json data to request body
JSONObject res=req.sendAndReadJSON();//Accept response as JSONObject
```

**Example 6**:

```
//Equivalent to previous example, but in a shorter way (using methods chaining):
String json="{\"name\":\"Deadpool\",\"age\":40}";//JSON that we need to send
String url="http://some.url";//URL address where we need to send it 
//Shortcut for example 5 complex request sending & reading response in one (chained) line
JSONObject res=new HttpRequest(url).withHeaders("Content-Type: application/json").prepare(HttpRequest.Method.PUT).withData(json).sendAndReadJSON();
```

**Example 7**:

```
//Downloading file
byte [] file = new HttpRequest("http://some.file.url").prepare().sendAndReadBytes();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("smile.png");
fos.write(file);
fos.close();
```

Comment: Looks like the proper answer to this question

Comment: Best Example for deprecated httpClient, NameValuePair. Recommence to other.

Comment: how about upload file to server?

Comment: @DavidUntama Just send it as JSON and then use `GSON.fromJson` on your server to parse it.

Answer (score 7):

The following code is in an AsyncTask:

In my background process:

```
String POST_PARAMS = "param1=" + params[0] + "&param2=" + params[1];
URL obj = null;
HttpURLConnection con = null;
try {
    obj = new URL(Config.YOUR_SERVER_URL);
    con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");

    // For POST only - BEGIN
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
    os.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes()); 
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    // For POST only - END

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    Log.i(TAG, "POST Response Code :: " + responseCode);

    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
         String inputLine;
         StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

         while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
              response.append(inputLine);
         }
         in.close();

         // print result
            Log.i(TAG, response.toString());
            } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "POST request did not work.");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Reference:
http://www.journaldev.com/7148/java-httpurlconnection-example-to-send-http-getpost-requests

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution that I have applied to the problem that httpclient deprecated in this version of android 22`

```
 public static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";



public static String sendPost(String _url,Map<String,String> parameter)  {
    StringBuilder params=new StringBuilder("");
    String result="";
    try {
    for(String s:parameter.keySet()){
        params.append("&"+s+"=");

            params.append(URLEncoder.encode(parameter.get(s),"UTF-8"));
    }


    String url =_url;
    URL obj = new URL(_url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "UTF-8");

    con.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
    outputStreamWriter.write(params.toString());
    outputStreamWriter.flush();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + params);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine + "\n");
    }
    in.close();

        result = response.toString();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
    return  result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are free to continue using HttpClient. Google deprecated only their own version of Apache's components. You can install fresh, powerful and non deprecated version of Apache's HttpClient like I described in this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/37623038/1727132

Answer (score 2):

if targeted for API 22 and older, then should add the following line into build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
}
```

if targeted for API 23 and later, then should add the following line into build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'cz.msebera.android' , name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1'
}
```

If still want to use httpclient library, in Android Marshmallow (sdk 23), you can add:

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

to build.gradle in the android {} section as a workaround. This seems to be necessary for some of Google's own gms libraries!

Answer (score 1):

> Which client is best?
>
> Apache HTTP client has fewer bugs on Eclair and Froyo. It is the best
>   choice for these releases.
>
> For Gingerbread and better, HttpURLConnection is the best choice. Its
>   simple API and small size makes it great fit for Android...

Reference [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) for more info (Android developers blog)

Answer (score 1):

You can use my easy to use custom class.
Just create an object of the abstract class(Anonymous) and define onsuccess() and onfail() method.
https://github.com/creativo123/POSTConnection

Comment: I believe it's better to use HttpURLConnection, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2938787/3281252.

Answer (score -1):

i had similar issues in using **HttpClent** and **HttpPost** method since i didn't    wanted change my code so i found alternate option in build.gradle(module)  file by    removing 'rc3' from buildToolsVersion "23.0.1 rc3" and it worked for me. Hope that Helps.