# DefaultHttpClient deprecated in API 22. How does it making right new network based application in Android?

Tags: android, networking, androidhttpclient

During the development of a new Android application, I needed to look for documentation for classes HttpClient package org.apache.http. I noticed amazed that the whole package has been deprecated in the API 22, and as a suggestion for [this page](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) recommend using [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). I learned that it is good practice to use less deprecated objects possible, but this is to revolutionize everything.

Here is my most useful code for performing network connection and handling responses.

```
public class Proxy {

private HttpClient client;
private BasicHttpParams params;


/**
 * This class encapsulates a generic response from the server. It store if response is success or not, if it is empty or not,
 * the possible code and message associate to response. Also can be stored a generic data passed from server in the response.
 */
public class ServerResult {
    //...
}

/**
 * This interface is an handler in the classes that perform the client-server communication.
 */
public interface RestRequest {

    /**
     * Callback method called when a server response should interact with elements into caller object.
     * @param result Entity that represents the response of the server.
     * @param requestCode An integer value returned to the interface to recognize which request is associated to result.
     * @param index If many request are done can be report index of i-TH request.
     */
    public void onProgress(ServerResult result, int requestCode, int index);

    /**
     * Callback method called when a server response should handled to caller object. This callback 
     * runs on UI thread. 
     * @param result Entity that represents the response of the server.
     * @param requestCode An integer value returned to the interface to recognize which request is associated to result.
     */
    public void onResult(ServerResult result, int requestCode);
}


/**
 * This function parse a json response from server in a valid assignable data content.
 */
private ServerResult deserializeResponse(String json, int type) {
    //...
}
/**
 * Perform generic POST request.
 * @param postData List of {@code (key,value)} pairs.
 * @param uri Url to send request.
 * @return Body of server's response.
 */
private String doPostRequest(List<NameValuePair> postData, String uri)
{
    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(uri);
    try
    {
        //  append postData to request
        postRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postData, HTTP.UTF_8));
        //  Execute HTTP Post Request
        return ProxyUtils.getResponseFromRequest(client.execute(postRequest));
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Perform generic GET request.
 * @param uri Url to send request.
 * @return Body of server's response.
 */
private String doGetRequest(String uri)
{
    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(uri);
    getRequest.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    try
    {
        //  Execute HTTP Get Request
        return ProxyUtils.getResponseFromRequest(client.execute(getRequest));
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return null;
}

/**
 * <p>The following object instantiate an async task thread where are performed web operations. Here can be execute only
 * execute GET and POST request.</p>
 * <p>Caller object must create it by constructor, giving appropriate parameters, then should call execute with a 
 * {@code List<NameValuePair>} arguments, that is entity of request. Also after thread execution this class give 
 * controller in the caller in {@code onPostExecute()} method, if is set callback object.</p>
 * @author Andrea Fabio
 */
public class RequestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<List<NameValuePair>,Void,ServerResult> {

    private String uri;
    private int requestCode;
    private int methodType;
    /** Object that invoke rest request */
    private RestRequest sender;

    /**
     * Caller must call constructor to perform web operations.
     * @param uri The web URI in http:// format.
     * @param requestCode Code for parsing each particular response.
     * @param methodType Code between {@link GET_REQUEST} or {@link METHOD_POST}
     * @param sender Object to handle callback interface implemented by caller.
     */
    public RequestAsyncTask(String uri, int requestCode, int methodType, RestRequest sender) 
    {
        this.uri = uri;
        this.requestCode = requestCode;
        this.methodType = methodType;
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    @Override
    protected ServerResult doInBackground(List<NameValuePair>... data) 
    {
        client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
        ServerResult result = null;
        switch(methodType)
        {
        case METHOD_GET:
            if(!data[0].isEmpty())
            {
                uri += "?";
                for(NameValuePair field : data[0])
                {
                    uri += field.getName()+"="+Uri.encode(field.getValue())+"&";
                }
                // remove last '&'
                uri = uri.substring(0, uri.length()-1);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Sending GET request("+requestCode+")\nUri: "+uri);
            result = deserializeResponse(doGetRequest(uri), requestCode);
            break;
        case METHOD_POST:
            Log.d(TAG, "Sending POST request("+requestCode+") \nUri: "+uri+" method, Entity: "+data[0].toString());
            result = deserializeResponse(doPostRequest(data[0], uri), requestCode);
            break;
        }
        client.getConnectionManager().closeIdleConnections(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if(this.sender!=null)
        {
            this.sender.onProgress(result, requestCode, 0);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ServerResult result)
    {
        if(this.sender!=null)
        {
            this.sender.onResult(result, requestCode);
        }
    }

}
}
```

And the helper class

```
public class ProxyUtils {

private static final String TAG = "ProxyUtils";
public static final int CODE_OK_HTTP = 200;

/**
 * To get content of entity from a Response provided by HttpClient connection.
 * @param response Result of connection from server.
 * @return If the header of a "200 OK" response contains the content of the response is decoded into a string 
 * otherwise {@code null }is returned if an error occurs between null response, header code> 400 or I / O errors
 */
public static String getResponseFromRequest(HttpResponse response)
{
    String result = null;
    if(response != null)
    {
        // server process request and sent a response
        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == CODE_OK_HTTP)
        {
            // accept response
            StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            InputStream is;
            try
            {
                //  Get InputStream to the response text
                is = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is));

                String line;
                // read all lines of response text
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    resultBuilder.append(line);
                }
                is.close();
                // end request call
                result = resultBuilder.toString();

            }
            catch (IllegalStateException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // error response
            Log.d(TAG, "Response: "+response.getStatusLine().toString());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // server didn't respond
        Log.d(TAG, "Server refused connection.");
    }
    return result;
}

}
```

I ask the best developer community on the web as you would change the code to avoid writing code deprecated. I also think that any improvements to the code are helpful for everyone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need an option to HttpClient in Android to send data to PHP as it is deprecated in API 22](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058727/i-need-an-option-to-httpclient-in-android-to-send-data-to-php-as-it-is-deprecate)