# Get JSON from URL - deprecated method?

Tags: android

I have been using this code to get JSON from a specified URL, but today I checked it, and everything in it is deprecated. It still works fine, but I want to know what is the new method of doing it?

Here's what I have:

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder("some url");
            HttpGet hg = new HttpGet(url.toString());
            HttpResponse hr = client.execute(hg);
            int status = hr.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity he = hr.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(he);
                jsonGet = new JSONObject(data);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The deprecated objects are `HttpClient`, `HttpGet`, `HttpResponse`, `HttpEntity` and `EntityUtils`.

EDIT: As suggested in some questions, this way

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
```

does not work for me, as I am getting `HttpClientBuilder cannot be resolved`

Comment: use HttpUrlConnection

Comment: care to give an example?

Answer (score 1):

Apache httpClient is deprecated with api level 22 you can read it about [this blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.tr/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html).

there is a new client for android now and it is very good.

but you can use [okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) instead (also back compat is possible).

**EDIT**
check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html#openConnection())(`URL.openConnection()`). this blog was posted in 2011 but they mentioned the deprecation there first as far as i know.

Comment: the blog post is from 2011, and i dont want to use external APIs

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to search well on Google.

Here is your answer may it will helps you.

The [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) documentation points you in the right direction:

`org.apache.http.client.HttpClient`:

> This interface was deprecated in API level 22.
>   Please use openConnection() instead. Please visit this webpage for further details.

means that you should switch to `java.net.URL.openConnection()`.

Here's how you could do it:

```
URL url = new URL("http://some-server");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

// read the response
System.out.println("Response Code: " + conn.getResponseCode());
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
String response = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(response);
```

`IOUtils` documentation: [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)
`IOUtils` Maven dependency: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.commons|commons-io|1.3.2|jar

Special Thanks to [fateddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4516887/fateddy) for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29060004/1318946)

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgapachecommonsiojar.htm

Download jar file from here

Comment: why do I have to download additional jar files? Is this really how Android wants us to do it?

Comment: Use of this file is to convert response from `InputStream` to `String`

Comment: I dont want to use external jar files

Comment: Then use `DefaultHttpClient`