# Android http post for api 22

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-post, httprequest

I used to do httppost like this:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.net/xxx/query.php?action=signin");
    String result = null;

    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", params[0]));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", params[1]));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    return result;
}
```

but as you know httpclient is deprecated over api 22. So i found a class 'HttpRequest' which you can find in this link [I need an alternative option to HttpClient in Android to send data to PHP as it is no longer supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058727/i-need-an-option-to-httpclient-in-android-to-send-data-to-php-as-it-is-deprecate)
I try this like this:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String result = null;

    try {
        HashMap<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
        values.put("user", params[0]); 
        values.put("pass", params[1]);
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest("http://example.net/xxx/query.php?action=signin");
        result = req.preparePost().withData(values).sendAndReadString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        result = e.getMessage();
    }

    return result;
}
```

but it gives an exception and exception message is the url("http://example.net/xxx/query.php?action=signin"). What am i doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: use `HttpUrlConnection`

Comment: may you give an example how to use that class to submit some values and get response as i mentioned above please?

Comment: use volley. Anway, if you've run into a problem why aren't you logging your exceptions to find out more?