# How to use URL Connection instead of HTTPClient in ANDROID to send POST request to PHP?

Tags: android, httpclient, httpurlconnection

I was trying to do this using HTTPClient since all the tutorials on the web are using HttpClient. But then I get the message *Cannot resolve HTTPClient* and that is proabably because it is deprecated since SDK 23. And there are not many tutorials to send POST request using URL Connection.

So can anyone please tell me how to do that ?
Basically let's just say, I ask user to enter the name and when he clicks submit button that is stored in PHP database.

P.S. : I know about ASynk Task, and I know Php and SQL.

Comment: I think you should read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post/31888919#31888919

Comment: This question appears to be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058727/i-need-an-option-to-httpclient-in-android-to-send-data-to-php-as-it-is-deprecate