# HttpClient deprecated, and URIBuilder not coming up?

Tags: java, android, deprecated, uribuilder

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<Pair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
        dataToSend.add(new Pair("name", user.name));
        dataToSend.add(new Pair("username", user.username));
        dataToSend.add(new Pair("age", user.age));
        dataToSend.add(new Pair("password", user.password));

        URIBuilder builder = //
        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: what URIBuilder not coming up mean ?

Comment: Your question contains no description of the problem

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058727/i-need-an-option-to-httpclient-in-android-to-send-data-to-php-as-it-is-deprecate

Answer (score 0):

In your project's `src/build.gradle`

add this line

```
 dependencies {
     compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0-alpha4'
  }
```

and now synchronise your project and also build your project.

Comment: is this supposed to give me access to HttpParams? It still comes up deprecated.