# How to upload strings and file to server in Android?

Tags: android, file-upload, server, request, httpurlconnection

I found many posts that used HttpClient and HttpPost in order to upload different types of data to a server, but now these method are deprecated.

Which is now the alternative to upload these types of data to a server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need an alternative option to HttpClient in Android to send data to PHP as it is no longer supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058727/i-need-an-alternative-option-to-httpclient-in-android-to-send-data-to-php-as-it)

Comment: try [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Answer (score 0):

Use **MultipartEntityBuilder** to send files

http://www.tauntaunwonton.com/blog/2015/1/21/simple-posting-of-multipartform-data-from-android

Comment: Android doesn't recognize the classe HttpPost and HttpClient, used in the tutorial linked.

Comment: buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

Comment: paste in your build.gradle and sync

Comment: Check weather it is recommendable or not. and proceed. good luck

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved with compile "cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.2"