# Connect to MySQL database using volley or other library

Tags: php, android, android-internet

In many websites tutorials connection to a database of MySQL in Android uses httpclient class and name pair values ,which is deprecated by Google .So how to do it using volley or any other library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your posting is RESTful, you can probably consume the service with Spring for Android: http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/

Keep in ind although that this is build for *Spring* web services. You might need to tweak it to support your service and method. Also and generic Java HTTP client API can be used to post data including Apache Commons:

[Sending POST data in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android)

```
String myPostURL = "http://yoursite.com/yourPost";
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
Object o res = postForObject(myPostURL, anObjectWithData, Object.class);
```

This will (if I am correct) POST form data to your url, and return an Object containing the response. You may or may not have to make sure that your Android data is posted as html form da.ta

Comment: What is RESTful posting?Can you please explain.

Comment: Are you using the standard http `POST` method? If so, then it is good. I probably shouldn't have said anything about RESTful because unless you are using SOAP or XML-RPC, or another protocol like that, then it *probably* is restful.

Comment: Yes i am using the standard http post method .

Comment: Then as in my post, any generic Java HTTP library should be able to post data to your post url.

Comment: Please show me how to do it,

Comment: If you look in my answer, it gives simple example, but I will mod it for you. If you are using Apache commons, see the link at the bottom.

Comment: Anyways thanks for the link at the bottom .It kinds of provide a workable solution for me.Thanks again for the help.