# Talking to PHP get commands from Android app

Tags: php, android, codeigniter, url

I have an android app and am trying to send data to the PHP on the server. The server gets the php data with

```
$this->get('uname');
$this->get('pass');
```

We do use codeigniter if that matters

The Java code, inside of an Async method, I currently have is

```
InputStream response = null;
URLConnection connection = new URL(urls[0]).openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("uname" , Username);
connection.setRequestProperty("pass", Password);
response = connection.getInputStream();
```

When I run this, the code always returns null but it is supposed to return a JSON array either way. I have checked the URL and it is correct. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android) question, this will help you

Comment: It's $this->input->get(); unless you have a method named get in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

You code should be like this
For your android side ,as mentioned by @Ichigo Kurosaki at [Sending POST data in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android)

For Codeigniter side , cosider you function name is user_login

```
function user_login(){
$uname = $this->input->get_post('uname'); //get_post will work for both type of GET/POST request
$pass =  $this->input->get_post('pass');
$result=$this->authenticate->actLogin($uname,$pass  ); //considering your authenticating user and returning 1,0 array as success/failure
$this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output(json_encode($result));
exit;
}
```