# Android: How to programmatically submit a form created as html string?

Tags: android, html, webview

Please help me how can i invoke a submit action after loading this `html`.

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);        
String formData = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
            "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\n" +
            "<head>\n" +
            "<title>SSO OutBound Settings</title>" +
            "</head>\n" +
            "<body>" +
            "<form name='frmMain' id=\"frmMain\" runat='server' method='POST'" +
            "action='" + ---data--- + "'>" +
            "<input type='hidden' name='" + ---data--- + "'" +
            "value='" + ---data--- + "'/>" +
            "<input type='hidden' runat='server' name='" + ---data--- + "' " +
            "value='" + ---data--- + "'/>" +
            "</form>" +
            "</body>\n" +
            "</html>";
webView.loadData(formData, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: You immediately want to submit the form, without any user interaction?

Comment: Yes, without any user interaction it should happen.

Comment: @DineshKumar if you get the solution for this , please let me know i have also the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd need to do this in javascript. So it would have to be enabled for your web view:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Submitting the form should be something like:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.frmMain.submit()");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use an http client for that - [Android HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), [Apache httpclient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html), [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) etc.
The idea is to send http POST with form data to requred resource.
See [Sending POST data in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android)