# Is it possible to connect an Android application to MySQL database, without Async tasks?

Tags: java, android, mysql

I'm learning Android development and mostly to retrieve data from the server side databases,I use Async tasks, to obtain data from PHP and MySQL.

I want to know whether is it possible to connect the android application directly to the MySQL database.What would be the adverse effects of doing so? And is there any example on how to perform CRUD operations using such direct MySQL connection?

Comment: Normally you use a on-device SQLite DB with Android and that is really easy to use and not totally different from MySQL.

Comment: I need to have a common database for all the users,so SQLite is not possible.

Comment: Just google "stackoverflow android xyz" fill in xyz. http://stackoverflow.com/q/36063130

Answer (score 1):

According to: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html
you can't networking in main thread and according to:

- [Can an Android App connect directly to an online mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217835/can-an-android-app-connect-directly-to-an-online-mysql-database)
- [Connecting to MySQL from Android with JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233145/connecting-to-mysql-from-android-with-jdbc)

Direct connection to MySQL in Android is not recommend/not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you anytime feel like using different `Networking Calls`. Use `Volley`, it is fast and better than `Asynctask` request. As per your question **network calls are not possible on Main UI**.

Try reading more about `Volley` which google introduced in 2013. A very good MySQL CRUD example on my blog. [here](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-mysql-tutorial-to-perform-basic-crud-operation/)