# How to send json object as request parameter in a url using HttpsURLConnection in android

Tags: android, json, httpsurlconnection

I am having a url as  https://www.xyz.in/ws/bt with Request Parameters as token,blockrequest and format.
Sample JSON “blockrequest” String is

---

```
{"source\":\"1492\",\"destination\":\"1406\",\"availableTripId\":\"100008417320611112\",\"boardingPointId\":\"1129224\",\"inventoryItems\":[{\"seatName\":\"21\",\"ladiesSeat\":\"false\",\"passenger\":{\"name\":\"passenger_name_1\",\"title\":\"MR\",\"gender\":\"MALE\",\"age\":\"23\",\"primary\":true,\"idType\":\"PANCARD\",\"email\":\"pass_name@domain_name.com\",\"idNumber\":\"BEPS1111B\",\"address\":\"passenger_address\",\"mobile\":\"xxxxxxxxxx\"},\"fare\":\"320.00\"},{\"seatName\":\"22\",\"ladiesSeat\":\"true\",\"passenger\":{\"name\":\"passenger_name_1\",\"title\":\"MS\",\"gender\":\"FEMALE\",\"age\":\"23\",\"primary\":false,\"idType\":\"\",\"email\":\"\",\"idNumber\":\"\",\"address\":\"\",\"mobile\":\"\"},\"fare\":\"320.00\"}]}
```

---

How can I send this data as a **request parameter** in the url using **HttpsURLConnection**.

Comment: With "as request parameter" you mean as HTTP GET request?

Comment: No, through HTTPS POST request.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2938787/793943 check this ans

Comment: It is not working for me. I need Https POST request using HttpsURLConnection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use Apache HTTP Client. Here's a code sample

```
protected void send(final String json) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare(); //For Preparing Message Pool for the child Thread
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); //Timeout Limit
                HttpResponse response;

                try {
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity( json.toString());  
                    se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                    post.setEntity(se);
                    response = client.execute(post);

                    /*Checking response */
                    if(response!=null){
                        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); //Get the data in the entity
                    }

                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    createDialog("Error", "Cannot Estabilish Connection");
                }

                Looper.loop(); //Loop in the message queue
            }
        };

        t.start();      
    }
```

This is imp line in above sample code:

```
StringEntity se = new StringEntity( json.toString());  
                    se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                    post.setEntity(se);
```

Try this.I hope it work.

Comment: Apache HTTP client is deprecated in was removed in API 23 (Android 6).

Comment: Use Volley library instead

Comment: Yes correct. Use volley or  retrofit. so you can easily send json body in request.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
URL url = new URL(yourUrl);
byte[] postData = yourJsonString.getBytes("UTF-8");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setDoOutput(true);

conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);
```

(For reading the response use the connection's `getInputStream()` method)