# CakePHP 3: validating user from mobile application

Tags: android, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.2

I'm working on a project which has Web Application and Mobile client. I'm using CakePHP 3.2 for developing web application. There is a table `users` to store user credentials and `register` `login` `logout` function.

I'm using `DefaultPasswordHasher` of CakePHP 3.

Now, I want the user to be able to register and login using Android/iOS application using the same `users` table and login using the `hashed password` generated by CakePHP or `hash password` while registration so that CakePHP web client can be used to login.

I'm a learner and new to CakePHP and Android.

How could I do it ?

The main problem is with the hashing of password field because CakePHP uses different technique to hash password every time.

> Edit 2

`login` action of `UsersController` in `CakePHP` project is configured to authenticate user and return to some other action. But I want to retrieve user's data after validating.

Comment: Please include some code, what you have tried so far?

Comment: actually I couldn't get how to do it. I'm asking for the guide how it could be done

Comment: you can use same user table and method, just check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android

Comment: please see `Edit 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using same `user` table you can `register` `login` and `logout` in your web application and android application .

please check this link [login](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html). its help you to solve your issue.

thanks.

Comment: I know how to do in CakePHP. I have already developed application in CakePHP. I want to know how to use `login` action of CakePHP controller and retrieve user data if credentials match in an Android application.

Comment: Please see my `Edit 2`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to retrieve user's data, dont use return $this->redirect().

just use something like this :

```
$user = $this->Auth->identify();
if($user){ return $user; }
```