# Android interact with php server

Tags: php, android

I have a problem with interacting with PHP server.

Comment: @FirstOne How can I change my code to Form-data? I am so confused. Thank you.

Comment: Can u put $_POST value in php? just write var_dump($_POST); in php file. Prolly php expecting array and you are sending json.

Comment: @MehmetSÖĞÜNMEZ I don't write PHP, I am just responsible for interacting.

Comment: [**Sending POST data in Android**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android)

Comment: /\ For the chosen answer, take a look at the `Older Answer` part

Comment: @FirstOne Thanks a lot! However, our product requires compatible with 6.0, is there anyway can fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Well, the `Older Answer` part is just like you are doing (`HttpClient` & `HttpPost`). If you are asking how to upgrade the code, that's a completely different question.. You'll have to search about that ^^

Comment: @FirstOne Thank you, I will try to figure that out. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Android [volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html), it is easy and simple with lots of functionality.

Reffer Following Block it might helps you..

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                 //GET RESPONSE HERE
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //ERROR Message
            }
        }){
    @Override
    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // Pass POST data here [ params.put(key,value) ];
        params.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
        params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
        params.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
        return params;
    }

};

RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```