# is it possible to Insert data from android to MySQL thorugh PHP But define the namevaluepair inside button onClick?

Tags: android

I've tried to find many post on `Stack Overflow` question, then I found a useful post about that [on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android).

But on that link, I found some code like that inside new class :

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "Hi"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
// Execute HTTP Post Request
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Actually I want to define the data inside `button OnClick`, **Because** I got all string through loop `for`.

For the example :

```
int size = adapter3.getCount();
for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
    id = adapter3.getItem(i).getId();
    nilai = String.valueOf(adapter3.getItem(i).getRatingStar());
    PostDataTOServer p = new PostDataTOServer(); // call the class insert
    p.execute(id, nilai);
}
```

So, everytime I loop, I need to call the `insert class` that define the String in button.

*Is there any method how to do like I need?*

Comment: You can modify the PostDataTOServe class, writing a method in which you can define the value pair

Comment: @MikeKeepsOnShine but how? I've read many times tutorials on google, but I did not find the way until now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class `PostDataTOServer` you can create a method in which you fill the NameValuePair list, e.g.

```
public class PostDataTOServer{

    private List<NameValuePair> values;
    // here I use an HashMap because I need a <K,V> object
    public void setDataToSend(HashMap<String,String> datas){
        //TODO: make a check on the size of HashMap
        values = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(datas.size());

        //iterate the HashMap and fill the valuePair
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : datas.entrySet()){
            values.add(new BasicNameValuePair(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
        }
    }

    ....

}
```

and in your for loop you must call

```
p.setDataToSend(hashMap) // p = new PostDataTOServer();
```

Then in `doInBackground`, you can use directly the valuePair created

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(this.values));
```