# How to send push notification on button click

Tags: android, json, push-notification, onclick, android-volley

I've create push notification for my android app, it's work when I try to send it from firebase console. Now what I want is make a push notification when user click on register then show the notification for other users.

I've search in google but didn't find one of the example. The goals is to notif other user that there are new user register in my app.

Thanks for help

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMessagingService";
    public static final int ID_SMALL_NOTIFICATION = 235;
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // ...

        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.

        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            sendNotification("Hi ini isinya");
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Message Notification Title" + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, ID_SMALL_NOTIFICATION, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String channelId = "fcm_default_channel";
        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                        .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(ID_SMALL_NOTIFICATION, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't get what you mean but you can use Volly Json object request

First you need to copy your **server key** from Firebase Console, open up [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com) and choose your project

Second add Volley dependency in your project

> compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'

then you can add this code to push

```
private void sendFCMPush() {

            String SERVER_KEY = YOUR_SERVER_KEY;
            String msg = "this is test message";
            String title = "my title";
            String token = FCM_TOKEN;

            JSONObject obj = null;
        JSONObject objData = null;
        JSONObject dataobjData = null;

        try {
            obj = new JSONObject();
            objData = new JSONObject();

            objData.put("body", msg);
            objData.put("title", title);
            objData.put("sound", "default");
            objData.put("icon", "icon_name"); //   icon_name
            objData.put("tag", token);
            objData.put("priority", "high");

            dataobjData = new JSONObject();
            dataobjData.put("text", msg);
            dataobjData.put("title", title);

            obj.put("to", token);
            //obj.put("priority", "high");

            obj.put("notification", objData);
            obj.put("data", dataobjData);
            Log.e("return here>>", obj.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.FCM_PUSH_URL, obj,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            Log.e("True", response + "");
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.e("False", error + "");
                        }
                    }) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("Authorization", "key=" + SERVER_KEY);
                    params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    return params;
                }
            };
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            int socketTimeout = 1000 * 60;// 60 seconds
            RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
            jsObjRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
            requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: tried this code but never get notification in any devices, any fix?

Comment: what error you get? what you mean by never get notification?

Comment: I put the code in my mainactivity, when try to click register button no notification in any devices, please help

Comment: have you change the token? FCM_TOKEN with your device token?

Answer (score 0):

You want to send a push when one user clicks to register to everyone else who have already registered, right?.
You need to make a HTTP POST request to this address:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

With a header called "Authorization" with value like this "key=AIza...".

So in the body of the request you send a JSON like this.

```
{
  "to": "/topics/foo-bar",
  "data": {
    "message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
   }
}
```

And then you need to create a topic and subscribe the device to the same topic.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("foo-bar");
```

That should work just fine.

Comment: so where i need to add those code? inside the android app project or php files?

Comment: When your user clicks to register, you should register him and do a HTTP request in parallel

Comment: I can tell you what you will need to do so, and you go look forward. Okay? Not being rude. You need to use an AsyncTask or use Retrofit to make the HTTP request. There is plenty of examples here in stackoverflow.

Comment: still didn't get a solution, what code should I add in android using HTTP request?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android