# How to make a cURL command into a HTTP POST?

Tags: android, curl, http-post

Would anyone be able to help convert the following cURL command to a HTTP POST which can be run from a button click on an Android App?

**cURL Command:**

```
'C:\\DevPrograms\\curl-7.59.0-win32-mingw\\bin\\curl.exe' -X POST --data-binary '@C:\xampp\htdocs\Pastec_Test_Connection\Test_Images\Test_FiveHundredEuro01.jpg' 'http://localhost:4212/index/searcher'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending POST data in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android)

Comment: Please do not post the same question within two hours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49832174/android-is-it-possible-to-send-a-command-from-an-android-app-to-a-web-page-to-t?noredirect=1#comment86681144_49832174

Answer (score 0):

Given below are the codes to:

- Load a JPG as bitmap.
- Convert the bitmap into Byte Array.
- Sending a POST through [HttpURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) with Byte Array.
- Getting the response from server.

---

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File("C:/xampp/htdocs/Pastec_Test_Connection/Test_Images/Test_FiveHundredEuro01.jpg"));
InputStream stream = null;

try {
    stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, options);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("IOException", e.getMessage(), e);
    return null;
} finally {
    try {
        if (stream != null) stream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = null;
byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteStream);
// Convert ByteArrayOutputStream to byte array. Close stream. 
byte[] byteArray = byteStream.toByteArray();
byteStream.close();
byteStream = null;

URL url = null;
try {
    url = new URL("http://localhost:4212/index/searcher");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
try {
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
try {
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
} catch (ProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(byteArray.length));
conn.setUseCaches(false);
try {
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream()) {
        wr.write(byteArray);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Get Response  
    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
        response.append('\r');
    }
    rd.close();
    System.out.println(response.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you @Midhun, but its having issues with `HTTPClient`?

Comment: What kind of issues? Please elaborate.

Comment: `Cannot Resolve Symbol DefaultHttpClient` or `Cannot Resolve Symbol BasicHttpParams` or `Cannot Resolve Symbol HttpPost` for example

Comment: Add this to your **gradle** `compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.5'` or `android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}`

Comment: HttpClient is scheduled for removal in Android 6.0 and above.. Are you building the app for 6.0+? Then you will have to switch from HttpClient to HttpURLConnection

Comment: Introducing those to the gradle worked for the http issues, Just one with `TAG` and `UTF_8` left

Comment: Yeah it is for 6.0+ primarily but if I get this working for now I will then work towards converting it over

Comment: I updated the code
replace TAG by "IOException"
and UTF_8 by StandardCharsets.UTF_8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168995/discussion-between-midhun-varghese-and-jay1995).