# How to send POST data with android webview to login to a website?

Tags: java, android, html

I am creating an android app that uses the webview to open a website. My goal is for the user to never have to log back into the website once they already have. I am attempting to use POST data sent from the webview to the website with the user's username and password.

The section of html that I will be posting to is

```
<form action="" method="post" class="loginPad" autocomplete="off">
  <h1 class="vPurple text-center loginText">
    <i class="icon icon-lock vPink"></i> 
    Login 
    <span class="blink_text vPurple">&gt;_</span>
  </h1>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username" class="form-control rounded input-lg text-center no-border"
  </div>    
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" class="form-control rounded input-lg text-center no-border">
  </div>
</form>
```

And then for android I have:

```
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

        final MainActivity activity = this;

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                //Users will be notified in case there's an error (i.e. no internet connection)
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
            }
        });

        String url = "http://www.*****.com/login.php";
        String userName = "exampleUsername";
        String password = "examplePassword";
        String postData = "username="+userName+"& password="+password;

        webView.postUrl(url, postData.getBytes());
```

With what I have, the webview loads the login page but doesn't do anything else.

Comment: Consider doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android. Using a WebView seems to be unnecessary here. You can capture user name and password in a native ui and pass it like that.

Comment: So make a native login page and then pass the credentials to the webview?