# Android. sending POST request to Google Sheet script

Tags: java, android, post, google-apps-script, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to send data from Android to a script in a google Spreadsheet via a POST request. I get no errors but the request doesn't seem to go through.

I've tried some of the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android)

I tried the script with a simple form and it works, but from android it doesn't look like anything is even trying to get to it.

---

I use 2 classes for this, one extends `AppCompatActivity` and the other extends `AsyncTask`

```
public class FormActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// STUFF    

    private void sendData() {

        // Post Request

        int data1 = SOMEDATA1;
        int data2= SOMEDATA2;
        String sdata1 = Integer.toString(data1 );
        String sdata2 = Integer.toString(data2);

        String urlString = MYSCRIPTURL; // URL to call
        String data = "data1=" + data1 + "&data2=" + data2 ; //data to post

        MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask();
        myAsyncTask.execute(urlString, data);

    }
}
```

---

This is the class that should do the POST request

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String urlString = params[0]; // URL to call
        String data = params[1]; //data to post
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());

            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(data);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            out.close();

            urlConnection.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

I have also added

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

to the manifest.

This seems to run fine until the end but on the side of the script the log shows nothing.

The method `doInBackground` in the answer to the question I linked is void but Android Studio only accepts it as string for me. Apart from that and a few additions the code is the same.

EDIT: I also tried using GET, doesn't work.

Comment: By any chance did you create a doPost() function.  You might want to take a look at this https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: In your Script>View> Executions. See if it ran?

Comment: Yes, I have a working doPost() function, it works fine with a simple html form.

Comment: The Executions don't show anything new when I try from android.