# HTTP POST method says 404 file not found exception on Android

Tags: java, android, asp.net-web-api, filenotfoundexception

I have a simple web api which receives a parameter as string and return a "success" string  as response.
I have tested the api url with POSTMAN App and I got response as "success"

- url  : http://www.xxx.co/testapi/testmethod
- Method : POST
- Params : key=val ; value=Hai
- Postman return as : "success"

My code in android is:

```
public static String tryPOSTScript(){
 Log.d("TAG","App1 inside tryPOSTScript");

 String data = "val=Hai";
 URL url = null;
 try {
 url = new URL("http://www.xxx.co/testapi/testmethod");
 } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
 Log.d("TAG","App1 Exception MalformedURLException: "+e.toString());

 e.printStackTrace();
 }
 HttpURLConnection con = null;
try {
 con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 con.setRequestMethod("POST");
 con.setDoOutput(true);
 con.getOutputStream().write(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
 con.getInputStream();
 } catch (IOException e) {
 Log.d("TAG","App1 Exception IOException: "+e.toString());

 e.printStackTrace();
 }

return data;

 }
```

And I got the response as

> Exception IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.xxx.co/testapi/testmethod
>   Exception responseCode: 404

Please help to correct it. If file not found How can I get it correctly with postman app?

Comment: Opening the link in browser indicates 404 error. You should check your path

Comment: Can you post your Postman Response?

Comment: xxx.co is dummy.original one cant be show here. Because web api is not authenticated now. postman return success

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android

Comment: Check this one. It might help