# Service android json or soap?

Tags: android, json, soap

iam about to call a service from my server.
Should I use Json or Soap?

My service is in asp.net

Are there not any packages in android that has to do with the service connections?

Comment: JSON is very easy to handle in Android. I have't used SOAP though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, a REST interface encoded in JSON will be easier in Android, since there are enough classes built in to handle that. SOAP requires a third-party JAR (e.g., kSOAP2).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Iam going to send pictures, and a large texts. is jason sufficient? 
What kind of service should create in .net, a asmx-file or WCF REST?

Comment: By the way do you have any samples of the json? (Iam new to this)

Comment: @Troj: I wouldn't touch .NET with a 10-meter pole, so I have no recommendations there. JSON does not handle pictures; AFAIK, neither does SOAP. I recommend a RESTful service, where you `HTTP PUT` the images and other resources. There are a variety of books on how to create such Web services (e.g., _RESTful Web Services_).

Comment: CommonsWare why exactly wouldn't you touch .NET?

Comment: @tobson: Just personal preference. I gave up on MS server-side a decade ago and haven't exactly missed it. It also runs really lousy on my Linux servers. :-) More seriously, I'm just saying I have no advice on .NET implementations of Web services. I apologize for any confusion my glib comment may have caused.

Comment: I disagree, MVC is pretty awesome. I developed a web service in C# for my Android project and they work very well together. Note that C# and Java are quite similar so it's easy to work on one project or the other without much of a brain switch. The only disadvantage to .Net is that hosting it is more expensive than the Linux alternative. Also, web deployment from Visual Studio is exceedinly convenient.

Answer (score 0):

On how to use JSON in Android [Sending and Parsing JSON Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/)

You could use Http Client and MultiPart Entities for sending images and large text files. [Sending images using Http Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935946/)

Answer (score 0):

Json will also be more efficient than soap as well. Check out the Google Io videos from2009. There is a great talk about optimizing apps on android and it specifically deals worth this topic...

Answer (score 0):

JSON is always easier...it's much easier to parse and doesn't need a DTD..