# How can you upload photos from android gallery to server?

Tags: android, photo, ksoap

I am writing an android application in which users can pick a photo from their gallery and upload it to a server. How should I accomplish this ?

The application mainly uses SOAP webservices to communicate with the server, but I do not know how to serialize a stream of bytes in KSOAP and therefore I need some help. The solution should not necessarily use KSOAP. A valid solution would be to upload the photo on some server, and just retrieve the URL, which will be stored in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Http Component Libraries](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) for the purpose.

Check the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935946/sending-images-using-http-post).