# Android : Getting byte[] from Image ID

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

Here is what I am doing:

In onActivityResult, I get the data in an Intent.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
 startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

This code gets the image ID:

```
data.getData().getLastPathSegment();
```

Now i want to use this image ID to get byte[] imageData so I can upload the image on a server.

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(selectedImageUri, projection, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
cursor.close();

try 
{
    File myFile = new File(selectedImagePath);
    int filelenghth=(int)myFile.length();
    byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [filelenghth];
    BufferedInputStream bis1 = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));

    bis1.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);

    dos.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);   // write the array to the data output stream
                                                   // or whatever else you want to do with it
    finish();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Abhishek. This well help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

data.getData() will return to you a URI for your image. (Check data != null first!)

then you just need to perform a http post to your server.

See the following reference on SO for the http post code:  [Sending images using Http Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935946/sending-images-using-http-post)