# Image can't display on <input type="file" > Android 4.0.4

Tags: android, html, cordova

I want to upload an image with html , but always fail. I check via console.log and it generates below messages.

```
07-31 19:09:07.071: I/Web Console(16417): size:66797 at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:18
07-31 19:09:07.091: I/Web Console(16417): lastModifiedDate:Tue Jul 30 2013 03:44:18 GMT+0700 (WIT) at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:18
07-31 19:09:07.101: I/Web Console(16417): fileSize:66797 at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:18
07-31 19:09:07.111: I/Web Console(16417): name:1375130658314.jpg at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:18
07-31 19:09:07.121: I/Web Console(16417): type: at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:18
07-31 19:09:07.121: I/Web Console(16417): fileName:1375130658314.jpg at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:18
07-31 19:09:07.121: I/Web Console(16417): webkitSlice:function webkitSlice() { [native code] } at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:18
```

I find that "type" property is empty. It happened at android 4.0.4.

But it is OK on 4.1.2 and 4.1.3.

Is there any clue on this issue ?

--

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Image preview example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
oFReader = new FileReader(), 
rFilter = /^(?:image\/bmp|image\/cis\-cod|image\/gif|image\/ief|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/pipeg|image\/png|image\/svg\+xml|image\/tiff|image\/x\-cmu\-raster|image\/x\-cmx|image\/x\-icon|image\/x\-portable\-anymap|image\/x\-portable\-bitmap|image\/x\-portable\-graymap|image\/x\-portable\-pixmap|image\/x\-rgb|image\/x\-xbitmap|image\/x\-xpixmap|image\/x\-xwindowdump)$/i;

oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
   document.getElementById('preview').src = oFREvent.target.result;
};

function loadImageFile() {
  if (document.getElementById("uploadImage").files.length === 0) { return; }
  var oFile = document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0];
  for(var x in oFile)
    console.log(x+":"+oFile[x]);
  oFReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
}
</script>
</head>

<body >
  <form name="uploadForm">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
         <img id="preview" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="" alt="Image preview" />

          <td><input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="myPhoto" onchange="loadImageFile()" /></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Send" /></p>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?
`<input type="file" name="photo" accept="image/*" capture="camera">`

Got it from here: [Does the android web browser allow uploading photos just taken from camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569919/does-the-android-web-browser-allow-uploading-photos-just-taken-from-camera)

There (were?) issues: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2519

I tried it once for an app based on PhoneGap for Android, but did not got it to work (did not try the html line above though. I found on the internet that it wasn't possible at that moment (was about uploading an image to use as an avatar in the app and website).