# Save and Access the data through web service in remote server in android

Tags: android, web-services, webserver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make an Android app communicate with a web server over the internet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501550/how-can-i-make-an-android-app-communicate-with-a-web-server-over-the-internet)

I'm trying to save the data (username & password ) in server and also access through the server every time when I'm logging.

How to create the connection class and and user class and access class in Android ?

Comment: You can use any web technology PHP, .Net, Java will all work. It can be rest or SOAP or non RESTful non SOAP plain JSON, XML or text.

Comment: check this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Comment: is that possible to write the code of another language in android it support or not ?

Comment: ok i check @abbas.aniefa  thax

Comment: @abbas.aniefa the link you post me of androidhive is not working if u have a another code post me

Comment: @NiravRanpara if you have a code especially xml post me
thax