# Save Image to web server (byte array)

Tags: android, android-image

I want to upload an image to server in the form of Byte array.. Here I am using surface view and 'Take Picture' button, when user click a take picture button, then

```
    TakePicture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera.takePicture(null, null, callback);
    }
});
```

and pictureCallback is:

```
       PictureCallback callback = new PictureCallback(){

 public void onPictureTaken(**byte[] data**, Camera camera) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     try {
            //async task for storing the photo
         Log.i("Picture Taken.", "Picture Taken.");

            new SavePhotoTask(CameraPreviewActivity.this, data).execute();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            //some exceptionhandling
            Log.i("Save Photo exception",e.getMessage());
        }
```

}};
Now here I am using this byte array 'data'

and I want to send this image in the form of byte[] to web server..

What should I do for this??

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935946/sending-images-using-http-post

Comment: A complete Tutorial - http://getablogger.blogspot.in/2008/01/android-how-to-post-file-to-php-server.html

Answer (score 0):

convert byte array to base64

```
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

also see [this link](http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-base64-encode-decode-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

1)Send camera intent

```
public void onCameraClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    imageFile = FileUtil.newFile();
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

2)get file path when the picture will be ready, read bytes from file and send bytes to a server.

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                final String path = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
// get file from path and send bytes to server
            }
        }
    }
```